# Idiomatic way to await background tasks with redux + redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my application, we have a somewhat long-running "provisioning" task that asynchronously completes that we essentially have to use polling to detect that it has finished. So that a user isn't blocked from using the app while this takes place, we kick that off at the beginning of the user interaction flow. However, at the end of the interaction flow, the user takes an action that needs to await that provisioning task if it hasn't completed. Here's a sort of sequence diagram to illustrate.

```
[provisioning start][poll for completion....]
[user interactions]      [blocked action....][post provisioning task]
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out an idiomatic way to do this properly in Redux. Here are some things I've considered doing:

1. Have a "requests" reducer, where I'd store the `Promise` for that long-running provisioning task, then when `[blocked action]` executes, it simply awaits the promise. The problem with this is that Redux specifically requests that all store state is *serializable*, so it seems that things like Promises are not welcome there.
2. Subscribe to the store in the `[blocked action]` action creator and look for data that signals the provisioning has completed. Unfortunately, `redux-thunk`, which I'm pretty fond of, doesn't contain a reference to the store, just its `dispatch` and `getState` methods.
3. Having my React component wait for the provisioning to complete before executing `[blocked action]`. I don't like this because it adds too much action sequencing logic awareness to my view layer.

Since none of these seem like great options, I'm currently going with:

4. Store the provisioning `Promise` in a module property and essentially do option #1 without getting the `Promise` from the store. I'm not wild about this, since it moves state outside of the redux loop, but it seems like the easiest option.

Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this with `redux-thunk`? If there's another asynchronous middleware that makes this cleaner, I'm willing to consider, though I'm already quite invested in `redux-thunk`.

Comment: What does the shape of your state look like at present?

Comment: Simplification, but sort of like `{ infoUsedForSetup, postSetupInfo, laterActionIsPending }`, where I need `postSetupInfo` to be present before I can perform a particular action. But I want to obscure this from the customer; I want them to perform the action, set `laterActionIsPending` to signal displaying a "waiting" screen in the UI, then have that clear when complete, whether or not we had to wait on `postSetupInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several redux-promise-middleware options that let you dispatch promise actions and have the middleware consume them and emit PENDING,RESOLVED|REJECTED actions as the promise state changes.  If you are working with promises and Redux, you might want to look at one of them.  However they won't help you with this *specific* problem.

I think [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) is a middleware well suited to help you with this scenario.  I've not yet used it personally so I can't provide an example.

Another, perhaps simpler, option is [redux-tap](https://github.com/markdalgleish/redux-tap).  Use tap to expose the stream of actions that your app can subscribe to.  Have a blocked action creator thunk subscribe to that stream and await the action that signals that the promise has completed (it should of course first check the contents of the store via `getState` to see if the promise completed before this blocked action was dispatched).  Something like this:

```
// ========= configureStore.js
import ee from 'event-emitter';

// ...
export const actionStream = ee();

// ...
const emitActions = tap(({type} => type, (type, action) => actionStream.emit(type, action);

// install emitActions middleware to run *after* thunk (so that it does not see thunk actions but only primitive actions)


// =========== your action module.js
import {actionStream} from './configureStore';

export function blockedAction(arg) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        if (getState().initDone) {
            return dispatch({type: "blockedAction", payload: arg});
        }

        // wait for init action
        actionStream.once("initAction", initAction => dispatch({type: "blockedAction", payload: arg}));
    };
}
```

Keep in mind that it is not a binary "either thunk or xxx middleware" choice.  You can load thunk as well as many other middlewares.  In one app, I use:

- thunk
- a promise middleware
- console logging middleware
- custom middleware for batching updates
- custom middleware for persisting actions to IndexedDB
- custom middleware for pausing the action stream
- middleware to prevent recursive store notifications

Without any middleware other than thunk, here is another option:

Option 5 - combine your option 2 with your option 4: Store the promise somewhere globally.  Have the blocked action creator thunk await the promise before dispatching the raw action.  To minimize the "state outside of the store", you can also have the promise action emit actions into the store to keep the store updated (possibly using a promise middleware)

Comment: Your option 5 is pretty much what I meant by option 4, and it seems to be working ok for now. This `redux-tap` doesn't look like it would allow an action creator to subscribe to an action stream, though it does look like something amazing for app-level action subscription. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I added an example of what I meant with `tap`.

Comment: I see, thank you. So far it seems I'll need to either have a global store reference that I subscribe to or a global Promise to await. The Promise seems like the simpler answer here. But I do see that you can [inject a custom argument](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument) for thunks, so maybe the action stream from `redux-tap` could be injected as a `redux-thunk` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler—unless I'm missing something—if we're more rigorous in thinking about the UI as a function of state. At every point in your interaction flow there are a few things that are either true or false:

1. Provisioning has started/not started
2. Provisioning has finished/not finished
3. User action is pending/is not pending

These three facts are enough to tell us what the user should be seeing on their screen at a given moment, so our state should include these three facts:

```
const initialState = {
  provisioningStarted: false,
  provisioningDone: false,
  laterActionIsPending: false,
  // ...
};
```

Using redux-thunk we can handle the provisioning action:

```
function startProvisioning() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: START_PROVISIONING });

    pollProvisioning().then(postSetupInfo => {
      dispatch({ type: DONE_PROVISIONING, postSetupInfo });
    });
  };
}
```

...and in our reducer:

```
function appReducer(state, action) {
  // ...
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_PROVISIONING:
      return { ...state, provisioningStarted: true };
    case DONE_PROVISIONING:
      return { ...state, provisioningDone: true, postSetupInfo: action.postSetupInfo };
    case LATER_ACTION_PENDING:
      return { ...state, laterActionIsPending: true };
    // ...
  }
}
```

As I said, this should be enough to tell us what the user should be seeing:

```jsx
const Provisioner = ({provisioningStarted, provisioningDone, /* ... */}) => {
  if (provisioningStarted) {
    if (laterActionIsPending) {
      if (provisioningDone) {
        return <p>Finished! Here's your info: {postSetupInfo}</p>;
      }
      return <p>Provisioning...</p>;
    }
    return <button type="button" onClick={doAction}>Do action</button>;
  }
  return <button type="button" onClick={startProvisioning}>Start provisioning</button>;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Provisioner);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question isn't about what to show the user, but rather how to have the action wait until the the completion of the provisioning action before running. Maybe the part that wasn't clear is that I don't want the _user_ to be blocked by having the action available, but rather for the action to transparently wait for the provisioning so they don't have to wait before they can click a button, for example.

Comment: I understand that, but why does it matter if the action from clicking the button is dispatched immediately versus dispatched after provisioning finishes? If UI is a function of state, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly redux-thunk but functionally equivalent is using
[redux-background](https://github.com/monvillalon/redux-background). A package I created to make the process easier.

It goes something like this:

```
import { startJob } from 'redux-background';
import store from './store';

store.dispatch(startJob('provision', function(job, dispatch, getState) {
  const { progress, data } = job;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do some async stuff
    // Report progress
    progress(10);

    // Return value
    return 10;
  })
}, { data: '...' } );
```

On your state when it ends you should have something like this

```
{
  background: {
   provision: {
     active: true,
     running: false,
     value: 10,
     error: null,
     /* and lot of more metadata */
     ....
   },
  }
}
```